# Handling connection errors MySqli

Tags: php, mysqli

I am trying to simplify my mysqli, in case of a connection error I am using if and else, if it fails to connect goes to else. But this way I have to add two queries, start two connections. Two of everything.

```
$conn1= new mysqli($db_conn_server, $db_conn_username, $db_conn_password, $db_conn_dbname);

if ($conn1->connect_error) { $conn1->close();
$conn2= new mysqli($db_conn_server, $db_conn_username, $db_conn_password, $db_conn_dbname);

$sms_sys_query2 = "INSERT INTO `sms_messages_tbl` (`session_unq_id`)
VALUES ('$transaction_request_to_api_code')";   

    if ($conn2->query($sms_sys_query2) === TRUE) { $conn2->close(); exit();
    } else { $conn2->close(); exit(); }

}else {

$sms_sys_query1 = "INSERT INTO `sms_messages_tbl` (`session_unq_id`)
VALUES ('$transaction_request_to_api_code')";   

if ($conn1->query($sms_sys_query1) === TRUE) { $conn1->close(); exit(); 
} else { $conn1->close(); exit(); }
}
```

Could just starting a new connection with the same name do the trick?

```
$conn1= new mysqli($db_conn_server, $db_conn_username, $db_conn_password, $db_conn_dbname);

if ($conn1->connect_error) { $conn1->close();
    $conn1= new mysqli($db_conn_server, $db_conn_username, $db_conn_password, $db_conn_dbname);
}


$sms_sys_query1 = "INSERT INTO `sms_messages_tbl` (`session_unq_id`)
VALUES ('$transaction_request_to_api_code')";  

if ($conn1->query($sms_sys_query1) === TRUE) { $conn1->close(); exit();  
} else { $conn1->close(); exit(); }
}
```

I'm a newb to this, so If theres a better way of doing it... please let me know :)

Comment: How are you expecting this to work? If it fails once what on earth makes you think it will work one line down?

Comment: *Why* are you doing two connections to begin with...?!

Comment: the way you're doing it is fine but if the connection fails the first time it's going to fail the second time, no use trying to reconnect. instead of trying to reconnecct in teh `if(error){..}` just show a message and call `exit;`

Comment: one of the definitions of insanity is trying to do the same thing over again and expecting different results. if the first connection fails, the second connection is **HIGHLY** likely to fail as well.

Comment: @MarcB Thanks for calling me insane! I'm sure when you were starting to learn you knew EVERYTHING!!!

Comment: well, think about it: how can a connection fail? db is down. network is down. invalid connection credentials. db is bad/corrupted, blah blah blah. while it is microscopically likely that the db/network may decide to start working again in the few microseconds between your two connection attempts, I'd rather bet on the 99.99999% chance that the db's dead/gone, and attempting more connection is futile. and if the db's totally dead, or you've got bad credentials, it's beyond pointless to keep trying.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$DBCOnnection = mysqli_connect(
            DB_HOST,
            DB_USER,
            DB_PASSWORD,
            DB_NAME
        ) or die('Error ' . mysqli_error($DBCOnnection));
```

This would do the job, where DB_HOST etc are constants.

If the connection fails, the script will die and spit out the error.

You would then typically pick up the error thrown and display an error page and log the error to your error.log file.